# Adding a node.js config file to .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

This is a very basic question probably, but I cannot figure out how to use .gitignore to ignore a file during commits.

I am creating a Twitterbot in Node.js and have a config.js file with all my API keys. That's all I want to hide.

Do I just make a file called ".gitignore" and type out the name of the file (in this case, "config.js") and save it in my repo?

I'm a total newbie so thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Yes, you should try that...

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's exactly what you do.

```
--MyDirectory
----.gitignore
----myconfig.js
----MyFolder1
```

Then create a `.gitignore` file and within it, just write

`myconfig.js`

Comment: So what happens when you want to make a change to the configuration file and commit that? This suggests you remove the myconfig.js from .gitignore  then commit then change .gitignore back to original and commit again?.